# publishEvent doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse

i have some problem with the Disruptor Framework.

The publishEvent method in the ringBuffer doesn't work.

and i get this error message.

> The method publishEvent(EventTranslatorOneArg, ByteBuffer) is undefined for the type RingBuffer

here is my java class.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer;

import com.lmax.disruptor.EventTranslatorOneArg;

import com.lmax.disruptor.EventTranslatorTwoArg;

import com.lmax.disruptor.*;



public class LongEventProducerWithTranslator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private final RingBuffer<LongEvent> ringBuffer;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public LongEventProducerWithTranslator(RingBuffer<LongEvent> ringBuffer)
    {
        this.ringBuffer = ringBuffer;
    }

    private static final EventTranslatorOneArg<LongEvent, ByteBuffer> TRANSLATOR =
        new EventTranslatorOneArg<LongEvent, ByteBuffer>()
        {
            public void translateTo(LongEvent event, long sequence, ByteBuffer bb)
            {
                event.set(bb.getLong(0));
            }
        };

    public void onData(ByteBuffer bb)
    {
        ringBuffer.publishEvent(TRANSLATOR, bb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was with the publish event Jar.

I re-imported the lib.jar into my project and it worked.

Thanks anyway.